# Difference between DateTimeOffset?(Nullable) and DateTimeOffset.Now

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable, datetimeoffset

How can I calculate the time between between a nullable DateTimeOffset? to DateTimeOffset.Now ?

I need the result like "x day y hours ago"

I started by doing something like this.

```
  var creationTime = //A nullable DateTimeOffset on Database    
  var difference = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(creationTime);
```

But since creationTime is a nullable time, it gives me an error and I can't really find the difference.

Comment: You can use the `-` operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on what difference you expect from a NULL database value you can simply handle this using the `??` operator:

```
DateTimeOffset? creationTime = null; // A nullable DateTimeOffset on Database
DateTimeOffset rightnow = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset somewhen = creationTime ?? rightnow; // if NULL, it's NOW
var difference = rightnow.Subtract(somewhen);
```

<sub>(could of course be shortend to using `??` just when reading the database value)</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Filburt. That worked in the first try. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

First test if it has a value with `HasValue` and if it does use the `Value` property to get the actual value

```
if(creationTime.HasValue)
    TimeSpan difference = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(creationTime.Value);
```

Or if you have a default value in mind you can use `GetValueOrDefault`

```
TimeSpan difference = DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(creationTime.GetValueOrDefault(default));
```

A final option would be to just use the `-` operator.

```
TimeSpan? difference = DateTimeOffset.Now - creationTime;
```

but note that `difference` will be a `TimeSpan?` and will be `null` if `creationTime` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I'll keep the idea of checking value in future.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this issue, here is the extension method that I came up with the help of above answers.

```
namespace Extensions{
public static class DateExtensions
{
    public static string GetDifferenceTillNow(this DateTimeOffset? datetimeoffset) {
        DateTimeOffset? creationTime = datetimeoffset;
        DateTimeOffset rightnow = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        DateTimeOffset somewhen = creationTime ?? rightnow;
        TimeSpan difference = rightnow.Subtract(somewhen);
        return difference.Days.ToString() +" days & " +  difference.Hours.ToString() + " hours ago";
    }
  }
}
```